# How to transition from splash page to main activity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, splash-screen, android-lifecycle

Currently, my app loads the splash screen and stays that way. I think my main problem is with the Android life cycle. I have the splash page as the onCreate, and the main activity (which starts with private final, below) is also onCreate, but I don't think this is correct. Also, each activity is in one java file. Is this correct? How do I get my splash page to load, kill itself, then load my main activity?

Here's my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.deliveryfor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.splash); 

        Thread Timer = new Thread() { 
            public void run() { 
                try { sleep(3000); 

                startActivity (new Intent ("android.intent.action.SPLASH")); 


                } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 

                } 

                finally { 

                    finish(); 

                } 

            } 

        }; 

        Timer.start(); 

    }

    private final LatLng LOCATION_STATE = new LatLng(49.27645, -122.917587);
    private final LatLng LOCATION_CITY = new LatLng(49.187500, -122.849000);
    private final LatLng LOCATION_YOU = new LatLng(49.187500, -122.849000);

    private GoogleMap map;



    protected void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate(null);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map  = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick_State(View v) {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_YOU, 9);
        map.animateCamera(update);
    }
    public void onClick_City(View v) {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_CITY, 16);
        map.animateCamera(update);

    }
    public void onClick_You(View v) {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_STATE, 18);
        map.animateCamera(update);

    }

}
```

And here's the Menu.java (splash page):

```
package com.deliveryfor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Menu extends Activity { 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.splash); }




    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the Splash Activity as a classical activity, and you have to declare in the `Manifest` that it will be the first launched activity.
Add this line into the activity splash tag:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Then, in your `SplashActivity.java`, in the onCreate(), you add the code that automatically launch your `MainActivity`.
I use a TimerTask like so:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent toHomePage = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(toHomePage);
                finish();
            }}, 5000);
```

`5000` means that the Intent toHomePage is gonna be launched after 5 seconds.
Hope it helps ya!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an Intent to launch your MainActivity. Right now the code for Menu does nothing apart from creating its UI. The [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) describes how to do this.

You will need something like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You may also want to reconsider using a splash screen altogether, unless you have a compelling reason for it (which does not seem to be the case). Read [this blog](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/) post for details. Here's an extract I find quite interesting :

> A splash screen can be used to make resources available before an
>   application starts. Personally I think it is not necessary in 98% of
>   the cases. It may be useful for applications actively relying on heavy
>   resources such as Google Earth, Sky Map, or games but this is not
>   applicable to simple utility applications such as feed readers, social
>   network apps, news readers, etc. You should not require a network
>   connection at startup nor do heavy computations.

Answer (score 1):

i use it like this:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity{
    private final static long SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;

    // SplashActivity --> serves as entry-point for the app at several situations
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);                      
         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

              @Override
              public void run() {

                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // close this activity
                finish();
              }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this Activity to first page as MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    oAuth_Model oAuth_model;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        showBasicSplash();
    }
    private void showBasicSplash() {
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    Handler handler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message m){
            if (getBoolean(Constant.AFTERLANG)){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Landing_three.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_Sec.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And added this Activity to Manifests.xml :

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And kill Mainactivity after intent to other activities.

```
finish();
```